# creating a custom label for axis y in ASP.Net chart as a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 3 point axis for `axisY` in a chart for ASP.NET.  Right now it shows 1, 2, and 3. I need to assign string values to the points. I have found that it is somewhere in here:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(??????);
```

Not sure how to get it not to have to take a `double` value and be able to assign a string to the point.

Comment: Why do you want to use a string?

Comment: because i need to label the points as Production and Non Production on the Y axis.

Comment: Chart1.AxisX.Labels = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
.. but that errors with "no definition for AxisX" .. so i know that it has to be done with this set ...

Comment: Chart1.Series[0].YValueType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String;

Comment: and then something like this: Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(??????);
but that is where i am lost

Comment: Why cant you `.Add(yourCustomLabel)`?

Answer (score 13):

You have to create a custom label, set its properties, then add it to the axis

What about this?

```
    CustomLabel label = new CustomLabel();

    label.FromPosition = -1.0;
    label.ToPosition = 1.0;
    label.Text = "0";
    label.RowIndex = 0;

    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Clear();
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(label);
```

This will render a 0 where the Y-axis meets the X-axis.

Comment: Sad this was not approved as answer. Many junior users just never care to or bother.