# C#, DataVisualization.Charting: assign custom labels to values on axes

Tags: c#, windows, charts, data-visualization, axes

In C# I am using the `DataVisualization.Charting` library for plotting. 
In a simple line graph, I would like to show some custom text on the x-axis on positions x=0, 1, 2, 3.

Something like this (in [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html), though):
[image]

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis(v=vs.110).aspx) is the documentation for Axis class, but I'm not sure what I should look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`AxisLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.axislabel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `DataPoint`. Description of `AxisLabel` property:

> Gets or sets the text of the **X-axis** label for the data point, series
>   or an empty point. This property is only used if a custom label has
>   not been specified for the relevant Axis object.

So your code can look like this:

```
DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint(1, 1);
dp1.AxisLabel = "Frogs";
DataPoint dp2 = new DataPoint(2, 4);
dp2.AxisLabel = "Hogs";
DataPoint dp3 = new DataPoint(3, 9);
dp3.AxisLabel = "Bogs";
DataPoint dp4 = new DataPoint(4, 6);
dp4.AxisLabel = "Slogs";
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp1);
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp2);
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp3);
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp4);
```

Or you can enforce 1=Frogs, 2=Hogs, 3=Bogs and 4=Slogs with following code:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;    
chart1.Series[0].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
chart1.Series[0].MarkerBorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chart1.Series[0].MarkerColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, 4);
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 9);
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(4, 6);
foreach (DataPoint dp in chart1.Series[0].Points)
{
    switch ((int)dp.XValue)
    {
        case 1: dp.AxisLabel = "Frogs"; break;
        case 2: dp.AxisLabel = "Hogs"; break;
        case 3: dp.AxisLabel = "Bogs"; break;
        case 4: dp.AxisLabel = "Slogs"; break;
    }
}
```

To achieve really the same as on the picture - axes on both sides - you would need to use [the following trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458791/ms-chart-control-two-y-axis).

It works for X axis only, for Y axis you can add custom labels as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993282/2224701).

You can also use labels of datapoints which appear inside the chart using [IsValueShownAsLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.isvalueshownaslabel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing worries me: when you do `dp.AxisLabel = "something"`, you don't specify to which axis you should add the label. In the documentation you linked it says it's for the x-axis. What's the equivalent for the y-axis? The image in my first post was just an example, I thought it would be straight-forward to adapt the example to my case. :/

Comment: @RickyRobinson Edited answer - there no equivalent for y-axis, added link how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your points with those labels as the x values:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY("Frogs", 1);
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY("Hogs", 4);
// etc
```

Or, you could databind the points using two arrays:

```
string[] xvalues = new [] {"Frogs", "Hogs", "Bogs", "Slogs"};
int[] yvalues = new [] {1, 4, 9, 6};
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xvalues, yvalues);
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks simple enough, but it seems that C# assigns Frogs to 1, Hogs to 2, Bogs to 3 and Slogs to 4 just because that's the order in which I add the points. In my specific case, I need to plot several points, not necessarily with increasing X-values. How do I enforce 1=Frogs, 2=Hogs, 3=Bogs and 4=Slogs?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled into this thread, while searching for an solution on similar problem - I wanted a simple solution to have total control over the labels on the primary X-axis.

All I needed, was to use CustomLabels, example :

```
double mPtr = 0.0;
double stepMeter = 1000;
double distanceMeter = 14200;
while (mPtr < distanceMeter)
{
    var customLabel = new CustomLabel();
    customLabel.FromPosition = mPtr - stepMeter / 3;
    customLabel.ToPosition = mPtr + stepMeter / 3;
    customLabel.Text = $"{(mPtr / 1000.0):f1} km";

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(customLabel);

    mPtr += stepMeter;
}
```

[image]

By the way, currently I am using this Nuget package [https://github.com/kirsan31/winforms-datavisualization], VS2002 / .NET 7. Contains great performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the "Format" property of the LabelStyle on your axis.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.labelstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

There's a few reasonable tutorials on using the charting library out there if you search for them. Here's one: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/getting-started-with-the-asp-net-3-5-chart-control

Comment: Setting the `Format` won't change an integer to a string.

Comment: No, it won't, but if you were binding a single collection, rather than adding / binding individual x/y coordinates, it's what you need to look at. And if you're manually adding points, why would you have entered integers in the first place?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide an example showing how it works? Unfortunately this property isn't used in the tutorial you linked.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example in which I add points such as `(2,0), (3,1), (0,3), (3, 4), (2, 5)` and on the x-axis it will show "frogs" on position 1, "hogs" on position 2, and so on?