# How can I change Windows Forms Chart control data?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

This is the code I'm using now:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rdn = new Random();
    for (int i = 116; i > 0; i--)
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY
            (rdn.Next(0, 10), rdn.Next(0, 10));
    }

    chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine; 
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;

    chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
}
```

What I get is:

[image: Chart]

But now I want to change it.

On the left side instead the numbers 0 to 10 to see the numbers 1 to 116
And on the bottom instead -1 to 10 to see 1 to 30.

And to draw a line starting at 116 until 1 according to the 1 to 30.
For example in 1 it's 116 then in 2 it will be 105 then 100…it's just for testing so it can be random or just straight line from 116 to the 30.

But I want to know how to use it how to draw a line starting 116 and moving down according to the 1 to 30.

Comment: What charting library is this?

Comment: I added a reference using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting; and the control is: using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart that i dragged over in my designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do. But this is how I interpreted your question:

> On the left side instead the numbers 0 to 10 to see the numbers 1 to 116 And on the bottom instead -1 to 10 to see 1 to 30.

I take this to mean that you would like to change the range of each axis, such that the X axis starts at 1 and ends at 30, and the Y axis starts at 1, and ends at 116.

> But I want to know how to use it how to draw a line starting 116 and moving down according to the 1 to 30.

I take this to mean that, in addition to the actual data series (i.e. your random points drawn as an XY scatter graph, as in your example), you would like a line overlaid on the chart area, where the line starts at the graph coordinate of (1, 116) and connects to the graph coordinate of (30, 1).

With that in mind, here is your original code with additions to accomplish the above:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rdn = new Random();
    for (int i = 116; i > 0; i--)
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY
            (rdn.Next(0, 10), rdn.Next(0, 10));
    }

    chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;

    ChartArea area = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

    // Set the min and max for each axis
    area.AxisX.Minimum = 1;
    area.AxisX.Maximum = 30;
    area.AxisY.Minimum = 1;
    area.AxisY.Maximum = 116;

    // Add a line on top of the chart
    LineAnnotation line = new LineAnnotation();

    chart1.Annotations.Add(line);

    // Set the annotation positioning to be relative to the X and Y axes
    line.AxisX = area.AxisX;
    line.AxisY = area.AxisY;

    // Set the actual annotation position and boundary. Disable
    // IsSizeAlwaysRelative so that the annotation's size is
    // determined by the absolute positioning of the boundary.
    line.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
    line.X = 1; line.Y = 116;
    line.Right = 30; line.Bottom = 1;

    // Format the line so it shows up better
    line.LineColor = Color.Blue;
    line.LineWidth = 3;
}
```

That results in a chart that looks like this:

[image]

(I didn't change the range on your random number generation, which you had set to select random integer points between 0 and 10 for both the X and Y coordinates, so the data series itself is of course clustered in the lower left of the chart).

Answer (score 2):

Your graph displays numbers from 0/-1 to 10 because that's the range of values you provide. When the numbers are higher the graph will change labeling to include them. As to your code you provide a random numbers hence your result. To get what you described your data points have to contain the specified values: {1, 116} {2, 105} {100, 3}, etc. I don't understand what's the rule behind this series so I wasn't able to continue that. But to give you an example I generating the following: {116, 1} {112.13, 2} {108.26, 3} etc - with each step 116 is decreasing by thirtieth part of 116:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 1.0; i < 30.0; ++i)
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(i, (116.0 / 30.0) * (31.0 - i));
    }

    chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;
    chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
}
```

And the result is the following chart:

[image]

If you need more control over your labels than you have to use `CustomLabel` and `ChartAreas` but it can be tricky. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993282/3330348) has some details